# How to use page control which I added from storyboard? Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I added page control from storyboard and don’t know how to connect it to code to make it work. Now when I change pages it doesn’t change dots. I have to use my page control in the middle of the screen. Are there any special functions?

These ones just add standard page control at the bottom of the page.

```
    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        orderedViewControllers.count
    }
    
    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
```

Comment: Add `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` to your page view controller guy to see what happens.

Comment: @ElTomato I added UIPageViewControllerDataSource and used before and after functions, all work correctly except pageControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use bellow:
[How to use page control](https://medium.com/@GhostLarsen/using-a-uipageviewcontroller-in-swift-4-part-1-41ae631394d6)